# Receiving error - Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when implementing React Spring basic example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, react-hooks

I have a `next` app. the code for the app itself (`pages`, `static` etc.) is in a folder in the repo. called `frontend`. The app. itself is served through an `express` server via another folder in the repo. called `backend`.

Firstly I'm not sure if having these two separated is best practice, but I personally like doing it that way. Both folders have their own respective `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.

I am also running `ApolloServer` on the backend express server via the `/graphql` endpoint. The app. works fine until I try to implement a component with react hooks. Namely the [very simple example provided by `react-spring`](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/basics) as shown below:

```
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring'

function App() {
  const props = useSpring({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 } })
  return <animated.div style={props}>I will fade in</animated.div>
}
```

I have renamed this from `App` to `SpringDemo` and it is called simply in a page component like follows:

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SpringDemo />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

On serving my app via the `express` server in the `backend` folder I get the following error in the browser:

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the 
body of a function component. 
This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

***You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)***

I don't believe this to be the case, from my respective `package.json` files:

`frontend/package.json`

```
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
```

`backend/package.json`

```
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
```

All versions seem to match at the latest `16.8.5`.

***You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks***

Not likely with a copy pasted example from the `react-spring` docs.

***You might have more than one copy of React in the same app***

I don't believe I do, from my `package.json` listed above but I'm not sure. I read this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14823 issue, which then pointed me to this https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2792 but I can't be sure that this is the cause. Looking at the `package-lock.json` file doesn't elucidate (at least to me) if I am indeed running a different version of `react`/`react-dom` via `react-apollo`.

Checking the `package.json` on the `react-apollo` repo. here: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/master/package.json suggests that they're running the same version of `react` and `react-dom`, though different to my version of `react` and `react-dom` as listed above:

[`react-apollo/package.json`](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/master/package.json)

```
    "react": "16.8.4",
"react-dom": "16.8.4",
```

I also don't know if this aligns with my version of `react-apollo`, or indeed if this is the cause of this problem.

How can I solve this problem and figure out if I am indeed running multiple copies of `react`/`react-dom`? This hasn't been a problem for me with anything else react based.

**EDIT**:

To hopefully help I've created gists of my respective `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files:

`frontend/package.json` - https://gist.github.com/benlester/c7d82d7ad46cae9b8972284baba003a6

`frontend/package-lock.json` - https://gist.github.com/benlester/8f85b3fa290e67445ee0b2df365d8307

`backend/package.json` - https://gist.github.com/benlester/0c8004bdbb5b87c50734ba8044c35cee

`backend/package-lock.json` - https://gist.github.com/benlester/29f7a25f2ee633a13bdbdcee28270ddf

`npm ls react` - `frontend`

```
frontend@0.0.1 [directory]
└── react@16.8.5
```

`npm ls react` - backend is the same as above.

Comment: How do you use `App` ?

Comment: Revised question to answer this.

Comment: Check your html. It may include react twice or include files from older builds

Comment: I've deleted my `.next` folder in my `frontend` folder. All HTML is rebuilt (to my knowledge), and the problem persists, so I don't think this is the solution.

Comment: Not sure why someone has downvoted this question? I can't be any clearer or concise.

Comment: Try removing `node_modules`. Installed packages versions might differ from `package.json`

Comment: @UjinT34 just tried this on both `frontend` and `backend`, the error persists after reinstalling packages.

Comment: @BML91 can you try `npm ls react` in your frontend folder and post the result ?

Comment: Added the output of `npm ls react`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing the structure of the project.

Instead of having a separate `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in each of the `frontend` and `backend` folders I now have a single `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in the root folder (along with a single `node_modules` folder).

I don't know why this fixes the problem, as outlined in my question above all of my `react` and `react-dom` versions seemed to align with one another and I was using hooks correctly.

I also don't particularly love this solution as it forces me (at least with a single repo.) to use a single source for frontend and backend dependencies.

If anyone knows of a better way of managing frontend/backend mixed deps. I'm all ears in the comments.